# How to make a scrollable screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter

As you can see, Actually I want to make the screen scrollable, In my Flutter project, on one screen I have used some rows, columns, and listview but when I scroll my screen this is not happening, while I have to take SingleChildScrollView but it didn't work. and I have tried replacing the column with Listview but it didn't work. I don't understand where is the problem, please give me a solution. and I have attached my code and share a screenshot of the app screen below.
it shows pixel error.

[image].

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/core/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/ui/views/movielist/movie_detail_view.dart';

class MovieListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MovieListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MovieListViewState createState() => _MovieListViewState();
}

class _MovieListViewState extends State<MovieListView> {
  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff070d2d),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      _buildHeaderSection(),
                      _buildSearchBar(),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      buildCategoriesSection(),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      buildListCategories(),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      _buildPopularTitle(),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      _buildPopularSection(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHeaderSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 80.0, 30.0, 60.0),
      // color: Colors.red,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => MovieDetailView()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Hi, Edwards!",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              new IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      //counter = 0;
                    });
                  }),
              counter != 0
                  ? new Positioned(
                      left: 20,
                      top: 20,
                      child: new Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        ),
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          minWidth: 14,
                          minHeight: 14,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          '$counter',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 8,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : new Container(),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ9CbZTM7W7VmNIGF36hIjpJcVoWEhbPGEGSw&usqp=CAU",
                  height: 50.0,
                  width: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchBar() {
    return Container(
      height: 50,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
      child: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        hintText: "search your movie",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey,
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget buildCategoriesSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            "Categories",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 150,
          ),
          Text(
            "See more",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildListCategories() {
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: categoryList.length,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return _buildCategoryItem(categoryList[position]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCategoryItem(String category) {
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      width: 80,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.adb, color: Colors.white,),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Text(
            category,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildPopularTitle() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            "Popular",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 150,
          ),
          Text(
            "See more",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildPopularSection() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 6,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return _buildPopularItem();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildPopularItem() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://d1csarkz8obe9u.cloudfront.net/posterpreviews/movie-poster-template-design-21a1c803fe4ff4b858de24f5c91ec57f_screen.jpg?ts=1574144362',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
       SizedBox(height: 5,),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text("data",style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red
          ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are having problem for that overflow? And your screen don't contain enough items for it to be scrollable in vertical manner.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned `SingleChildScrollView` should work, but your problem is that you don't have enough items to be scrolled according to your screenshot.

So please use enough items and try again.

And in your `_buildPopularItem()` widget, decrease the container width, that's why it says pixel overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,  This is my stupidity .

Comment: @NeeluModanwal happy to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This overflow is made from `_buildPopularTitle()` while you set fixed height from `_buildPopularSection` having `height: 200,`

if you look closely, inside `_buildPopularItem`

There is a `Container` with `height: 200,` and it is taking full height, so for rest of children `SizedBox h:5` and `Container Text` aren't having any spaces here, and creating overflow.

**Solutions**

- increase the height of `_buildPopularSection`
- reduce the container height inside `_buildPopularItem`
- wrap with `FittedBox(child: _buildPopularItem());`

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot I can see that your container is smaller by 21 pixels in height. Please increase it.

```
 _buildPopularSection() {
    return Container(
      height: 230,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 6,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return _buildPopularItem();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildPopularItem() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 225,
          width: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://d1csarkz8obe9u.cloudfront.net/posterpreviews/movie-poster-template-design-21a1c803fe4ff4b858de24f5c91ec57f_screen.jpg?ts=1574144362',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
       SizedBox(height: 5,),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text("data",style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red
          ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Replace the above code and it should work...